# Preserving Registers?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gdb, x86-64

Okay, so in C code, I have it looping through the command line arguments and printing each one out.  I compiled it and opened it in GDB to see what the main function looks like because I was attempting to do the same thing in assembly.  I ended up figuring out what my problem was - that my print function was using the same registers as the main function was.  I ended up just pushing each onto the stack before the function call and popping them back off after.  Only thing I don't understand is why this code doesn't seem to do that and why it doesn't run into the same problem as I was.

```
   0x000000000040052d <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000040052e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400531 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400535 <+8>:     mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400538 <+11>:    mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
   0x000000000040053c <+15>:    jmp    0x400561 <main+52>
   0x000000000040053e <+17>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400541 <+20>:    cltq   
   0x0000000000400543 <+22>:    lea    0x0(,%rax,8),%rdx
   0x000000000040054b <+30>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
   0x000000000040054f <+34>:    add    %rdx,%rax
   0x0000000000400552 <+37>:    mov    (%rax),%rax
   0x0000000000400555 <+40>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000400558 <+43>:    callq  0x400410 <puts@plt>
   0x000000000040055d <+48>:    addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x0000000000400561 <+52>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400564 <+55>:    cmp    -0x14(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400567 <+58>:    jl     0x40053e <main+17>
   0x0000000000400569 <+60>:    leaveq 
   0x000000000040056a <+61>:    retq
```

Any input is appreciated, thanks.

```
(gdb) disass 0x400410
Dump of assembler code for function puts@plt:
   0x0000000000400410 <+0>:     jmpq   *0x200c02(%rip)        # 0x601018 <puts@got.plt>
   0x0000000000400416 <+6>:     pushq  $0x0
   0x000000000040041b <+11>:    jmpq   0x400400
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) disass 0x601018
Dump of assembler code for function puts@got.plt:
   0x0000000000601018 <+0>:     (bad)  
   0x0000000000601019 <+1>:     add    $0x40,%al
   0x000000000060101b <+3>:     add    %al,(%rax)
   0x000000000060101d <+5>:     add    %al,(%rax)
   0x000000000060101f <+7>:     add    %ah,(%rsi)
End of assembler dump.
```

In fact I can't even seem to find where it's printing out in puts.  I must be missing something, just don't know what.

Comment: Check what `puts@plt` does. A sane guess is it first pushes the registers it's going to use.

Comment: That would make sense, I checked but it doesn't look like it, I'll update my post in a second to show what I've found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disassembly you show for puts is not correct.  Library symbols for dynamically loaded libraries are resolved, well, dynamically.  The compiler generates a call to a stub (*procedure linkage table* or **PLT**), the loader resolves that at runtime, the second time you call that function the address has been resolved and it runs faster.  Disassemble it on the 2nd iteration and you will see the actual puts code being run, and you will see the registers being pushed.

More info [here](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html).

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense now.  I knew I wasn't understanding something.

Answer (score 3):

This instruction:

```
 jmpq   *0x200c02(%rip)        # 0x601018 <puts@got.plt>
```

reads the quadword (8 bytes) from the address given by the offset from the instruction pointer and jumps there.  So to see where this is going, you don't want to use `disas 0x601018`, you want to use `x /1xg 0x601018` to see what is in those bytes (read the pointer), and then call `disas` on that value to see the actual code for `puts`

This stuff is all dynamic linkage stuff that is set up to call functions in dynamic libraries.  `plt` is an abbreviation for "program linkage table" and is a set of trampolines created by the linker whenever an object calls a function in some other dynamic library.  `got` is an abbreviation for "global object table" and is a table of function pointers built by the linker and filled in by the dynamic linker when the program is loaded.